# Java Queue of Interface type

Tags: java, interface, queue

I'm trying to make a queue of an interfaced type Player because I don't know what type of player will be in the queue, ie human, AI etc so I have an interface for what different players can do, ie makemove etc.

```
Queue<Player> players = new Queue<Player>();
```

However, queue cannot be instantiated because Player is an interface. How do I create a queue of an interfaced type?

Comment: but there are different types of Player implementation? How can I store them all in one queue?

Comment: @hagubear no, that's incorrect.

Comment: What is the exact and complete error message you get from the compiler? Reading it helps. Hint: Queue is an interface. You should choose what kind of Queue you want.

Comment: @JBNizet "Cannot instantiate the type Queue<Player>"

Comment: @JBNizet      No it's not. See khelwood's answer below. Also check out the error message posted by the OP

Comment: @hagu what you proposed in your comment and what appears in  the answer are completley different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a variable of type `Queue<Player>`, but `Queue` itself is just an interface. You need to instantiate a concrete implementation of `Queue`, such as `LinkedList`.

e.g.

```
Queue<Player> players = new LinkedList<Player>();
```